# Compare 2 files and remove any lines in file2 when they match values found in file1

Tags: python, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have two files. i am trying to remove any lines in file2 when they match values found in file1. One file has a listing like so:

File1

```
ZNI008
ZNI009
ZNI010
ZNI011
ZNI012
```

... over 19463 lines

The second file includes lines that match the items listed in first:
File2

```
copy /Y \\server\foldername\version\20050001_ZNI008_162635.xml \\server\foldername\version\folder\
copy /Y \\server\foldername\version\20050001_ZNI010_162635.xml \\server\foldername\version\folder\
copy /Y \\server\foldername\version\20050001_ZNI012_162635.xml \\server\foldername\version\folder\
copy /Y \\server\foldername\version\20050001_ZNI009_162635.xml \\server\foldername\version\folder\
```

... continues listing until line 51360

What I've tried so far:

```
grep -v -i -f file1.txt file2.txt > f3.txt
```

does not produce any output to `f3.txt` or remove any lines. I verified by running

```
wc -l file2.txt
```

and the result is

```
51360 file2.txt
```

I believe the reason is that there are no exact matches. When I run the following it shows nothing

```
comm -1 -2 file1.txt file2.txt
```

Running

```
( tr '\0' '\n' < file1.txt; tr '\0' '\n' < file2.txt ) | sort | uniq -c | egrep -v '^ +1'
```

shows only one match, even though I can clearly see there is more than one match.

Alternatively putting all the data into one file and running the following:

```
grep -Ev "$(cat file1.txt)" 1>LinesRemoved.log
```

says argument has too many lines to process.

I need to remove lines matching the items in file1 from file2.

i am also trying this in python: 
 `

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
s = set()

# load each line of file1 into memory as elements of a set, 's'
f1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
for line in f1:
    s.add(line.strip())
f1.close()

# open file2 and split each line on "_" separator,
# second field contains the value ZNIxxx
f2 = open("file2.txt", "r")
for line in f2:
    if line[0:4] == "copy":
        fields = line.split("_")
        # check if the field exists in the set 's'
        if fields[1] not in s:
            match = line
        else:
            match = 0
    else:
        if match:
            print match, line,
```

`

it is not working well.. as im getting 
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 14, in ?
    if fields[1] not in s:
IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: in file1 are there any line breaks?If so, how frequently.You say there are 19463 lines but in the example there is only one.

Comment: i fixed that, should be clearer now

Comment: thanks for fixing that. there are line breaks in each file.

Comment: If I run the test data you provided using the grep command as you input, I also get no output, but isn't that to be expected? The first file matches with everything in the second and the `-v` says show only non-matches of which there are none.

Comment: ah, i want to remove any matches from file2 which exist in file1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting lines from one file which are in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780203/deleting-lines-from-one-file-which-are-in-another-file)

Answer (score 11):

What about:

```
grep -F -v -f file1 file2 > file3
```

Comment: thanks, tried and i got no results removed.                              grep -F -v -f file1.txt file2.txt
<p> wc -l file2.txt
51361 file2.txt
</p> wc -l file1.txt
19463 file1.txt

Comment: @useBSD It is supposed to print on screen.Editing to reflect that.

Comment: i tried and again.. no lines in file3. grep -F -v -f file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
# wc -l file3.txt
0 file3.txt

Comment: if all lines in file1 match all lines of file2 then there nothing to display or save to file3.

Comment: why, I tried with your example input and it works fine.Could you please recheck your problem specification just in case you got any detail wrong?

Comment: yes, the grep is working as expected but not as needed. i need file3 to include only lines which do not match.

Comment: @useBSD: That's exactly what file3 will include. Running it against the sample data you provided will result in an empty output file because all lines in file1 match with file2.

Answer (score 1):

I like the grep solution from byrondrossos better, but here's another option:

```
sed $(awk '{printf("-e /%s/d ", $1)}' file1) file2 > file3
```

Comment: Great, I just utilized this method to extract all running and network-active Docker containers: `docker ps -aq -f status=running | sed "$(docker ps -aq -f status=running -f network=none | awk '{printf("-e /^%s$/d ", $1)}')"`

Answer (score 0):

this is using **Bash** and **GNU sed** because of the `-i` switch

```
cp file2 file3
while read -r; do
    sed -i "/$REPLY/d" file3
done < file1
```

---

there is surely a better way but here's a hack around `-i`  :D

```
cp file2 file3
while read -r; do
    (rm file3; sed "/$REPLY/d" > file3) < file3
done < file1
```

this exploits shell evaluation order

---

alright, I guess the correct way with this idea is using `ed`. This should be POSIX too.

```
cp file2 file3
while read -r line; do
    ed file3 <<EOF
/$line/d
wq
EOF
done < file1
```

---

in any case, `grep` seems to do be the right tool for the job.
@byrondrossos answer should work for you well ;)

Comment: is file 3 here an empty output file? or file1 the output?

Comment: file1 is the file with the lines to match (entries like `ZNI008` `ZNI009` etc). file2 is the file from which the matching entries will be removed. file3 is the results.

Answer (score 0):

This is admittedly ugly but it does work. However, the path must be the same for all of the (except of course the ZNI### portion).  All but the ZNI### of the path is removed so the command grep -vf can run correctly on the sorted files.

First Convert "testfile2" to "testfileconverted" to just show the ZNI###

```
cat /testfile2 | sed 's:^.*_ZNI:ZNI:g' | sed 's:_.*::g' > /testfileconverted
```

Second use inverse grep of the converted file compared to the "testfile1" and add the reformatted output to "testfile3"

```
bash -c 'grep -vf <(sort /testfileconverted) <(sort /testfile1)' | sed "s:^:\copy /Y \\\|server\\\foldername\\\version\\\20050001_:g" | sed "s:$:_162635\.xml \\\|server\\\foldername\\\version\\\folder\\\:g" | sed "s:|:\\\:g" > /testfile3
```

Comment: NOTE: Both the newly converted file and testfile1 are sorted first.