# How to remove duplicates respecting linebreaks?

Tags: sed, grep

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10210311) answer for removing duplicates from two files. Suppose `file1` consists of the following:

```
a
b
c
d
```

and file2:

```
a
b
c
cd
z
```

after running:

```bash
grep -F -v -f file1 file2 > file3
```

I get this in file3:

```
z
```

I understand why it removes the line consisting `cz`, but I want to stop that behavior. How to do that?

`sed`-solutions are also welcome. I have tried the following from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10218881/) answer with the same effect in `file3`:

```
sed $(awk '{printf("-e /%s/d ", $1)}' file1) file2 > file3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove lines present in one set from lines present in another file, you would:

```
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

> How to do that?

Use `-x` to match the whole line.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response. Using `-x` in addition to all the flags or as a replacement to some flag, e.g., `-v`?

Comment: Also, you said "one set". So can I add multiple files to the set and remove all the lines found in that set from _a particular file_ and generate a new one?

Comment: `Using -x in addition to all` See `man grep`. `can I add multiple files to the set` As I understand `comm -13 <(sort -u file1 file2 file3) <(sort file4`), see `man comm`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I will check out the resources.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#/\\<&\\>/d#' file1 | sed -f - file2
```

Convert file1 into a sed script and apply it to file2.

The sed script is an address in the form of regex and a delete command if the regex is matched, for each line of file1.

The regex matches a word (`\<` and `\>` match the start and end of a word boundary).

The output from the first sed command is piped into a second sed invocation using the `-f -` option and file2 is designated as the input file.

N.B. The `\` is doubled up so as to avoid misinterpretation by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` has a straightforward command line option for that: `-x`.

```
$: grep -vxFf file1 file2
cd
z
```

If for some reason your version of `grep` doesn't have `-x`, make your pattern file enforce the same result (and drop the `-F`).

```
$: sed -i 's/^/^/; s/$/$/;' file1
$: cat file1
^b$
^c$
^a$
^d$
$: grep -vf file1 file2
cd
z
```

When you have odd condition sets, you can also usually hack together a solution pretty easily in something like `perl` or `awk`.

```
$: awk 'NR==FNR{x[$0]} $0 in x{next}1' file1 file2
cd
z
```

Neither of these requires any specific ordering of either file.