# Deleting line in file that contain certain string taken from another file

Tags: sed, awk

I have two text files:

```
File 1:
abc 1x21
```

and

```
File 2:
sdc 1x43
xcvyu 03x01
abc 1x21
xyz 4x23
```

and would like to get

```
File 3:
sdc 1x43
xcvyu 03x01
xyz 4x23
```

Found something similar in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780203/deleting-lines-from-one-file-which-are-in-another-file) but it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solutions if you `GNU grep`:

```
$ grep -vxf file1 file2 > file3
sdc 1x43
xcvyu 03x01
xyz 4x23
```

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' file1 file2 > file3
```

didn't test, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|/&/d|' file1 | sed -f - file2 > file3
```