# bash delete lines in file containing lines from another file

Tags: bash, file, shell, line

file1 contains:

```
someword0
someword2
someword4
someword6
someword8
someword9
someword1
```

file2 contains:

```
someword2
someword3
someword4
someword5
someword7
someword11
someword1
```

So I wan't to have only lines from file1 which file2 doesn't contains. How can I do this in bash ?

That's the answer:

```
grep -v -x -f file2 file1

    -v for select non-matching lines
    -x for matching whole lines only
    -f f2 to get patterns from f2.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Lines from File which appear in another File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780203/deleting-lines-from-one-file-which-are-in-another-file

Comment: Yeah. I searching in google but I haven't found this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -vf`:

```
grep -vwFf file2 file1
someword0
someword6
someword8
someword9
```

Check `man grep` for detailed info on all the `grep` options used here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `comm` command as well:

```
comm -23 file1 file2
```

*Explanation:*

`comm` compares two files and prints, in 3 columns, lines unique to file1, file2, and lines in both.

Using the options -2 and -3 (or simply -23) suppresses printing of these columns, so you just get the lines unique to file1.

Comment: This does require the files to be sorted lexically.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines are unique, do a left join and filter out lines that exist in both tables.

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) -o0,2.1 -a1 | awk '!$2'
```