# How to remove lines from a file using a list of strings

Tags: shell

I have a file which contains 100 000 entries and have to search for existence of 2000 different strings. If the string exists then I have to remove that line. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: that string is not the complete line?

Comment: so you mean there are 2000 strings to search for? and if any1 amongst them occurs in a line then we have to delete the line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete lines in a text file that containing a specific string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-containing-a-specific-string) or [Deleting lines from one file which are in another file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780203/deleting-lines-from-one-file-which-are-in-another-file).