# Print lines from one file that are not contained in another file

Tags: perl, bash

I wish to print lines that are in one file but not in another file.  However, neither files are sorted, and I need to retain the original order in both files.

```
 contents of file1:
 string2
 string1
 string3

 contents of file2:
 string3
 string1

 Output:
 string2
```

Is there a simple script that I can accomplish this in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Lines from File which appear in another File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)

Answer (score 51):

```
fgrep -x -f file2 -v file1
```

-x match whole line

-f FILE takes patterns from FILE

-v inverts results (show non-matching)

Comment: @ysth : Yes, fgrep means (file)grep, hence the -f option.  This goes back to older versions of unix. I think the gnu grep makes such a distinction redundant. ;-) Incidentally, FILE can contain many lines of patterns to match.

Comment: @shellter: no, fgrep means "fixed" grep, I think; fixed strings instead of regular expressions, also invokable as `grep -F`.  I was suggesting it should be fgrep instead of grep, and indeed it has since been changed.

Comment: @ysth : Well in the book I read X years ago, they said (file)grep. Fixed(grep) per fixed strings also does a good job of describing the functionality. Thanks for sharing. Cordially!

Comment: @j.lee If this answer satisfy you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 6):

In Perl, load file2 into a hash, then read through file1, outputing only lines that weren't in file2:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %file2;
open my $file2, '<', 'file2' or die "Couldn't open file2: $!";
while ( my $line = <$file2> ) {
    ++$file2{$line};
}

open my $file1, '<', 'file1' or die "Couldn't open file1: $!";
while ( my $line = <$file1> ) {
    print $line unless $file2{$line};
}
```

Comment: Leave the filenames as arguments and call the script something like `except` so you can say things like `except file2 file1 > result`.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} (!($0 in a))' file2 file1
```

Comment: I think it should be `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1` observe the `!`

Comment: And `awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$0]; next } !($0 in a) || /^$/'` if you want to keep the  blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

`comm <(sort a) <(sort b) -3` → Lines in file b that are not in file a