# How can I find lines in one file but not the other using bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell

Imagine file 1:

```
#include "first.h"
#include "second.h"
#include "third.h"

// more code here
...
```

Imagine file 2:

```
#include "fifth.h"
#include "second.h"
#include "eigth.h"

// more code here
...
```

I want to get the headers that are included in file 2, but not in file 1, only those lines.
So, when ran, a diff of file 1 and file 2 will produce:

```
#include "fifth.h"
#include "eigth.h"
```

I know how to do it in Perl/Python/Ruby, but I'd like to accomplish this without using a  different programming language.

Comment: For more ways to do the same thing take a look at this [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036).  Keep in mind since all of these solutions do line-based pattern matching, you'll have to make sure you format your include lines the same way everywhere. Examples: `#include` will not match `#   include` and `"first.h"` will not match `"../first.h"` from a sub-directory, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Lines from File which appear in another File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's ok to use a temp file, try this:

```
grep include file1.h > /tmp/x && grep -f /tmp/x -v file2.h | grep include
```

This

- extracts all includes from `file1.h` and writes them to the file `/tmp/x`
- uses this file to get all lines from `file2.h` that are not contained in this list
- extracts all includes from the remainder of `file2.h`

It probably doesn't handle differences in whitespace correctly etc, though.

EDIT:
  to prevent false positives, use a different pattern for the last grep (thanks to jw013 for mentioning this):

```
grep include file1.h > /tmp/x && grep -f /tmp/x -v file2.h | grep "^#include"
```

Comment: Maybe change that last grep pattern to `'^#include'` unless you also want to see random lines of code where you happened to use the word "include"

Comment: when greping for matching lines, you should use the options: `-F` for "fixed-string" (non-regexp) patterns, and `-x` for "whole line" matches.  Also, the temp file isn't strictly necessary, you can use `-f -` to take the pattern file from standard in.  The resulting command becomes: `grep '^#include' file1.h | grep -f - -vFx file2.h | grep '^#include'`

Answer (score 25):

This is a one-liner, but does not preserve the order:

```
comm -13 <(grep '#include' file1 | sort) <(grep '#include' file2 | sort)
```

If you need to preserve the order:

```
awk '
  !/#include/ {next} 
  FILENAME == ARGV[1] {include[$2]=1; next} 
  !($2 in include)
' file1 file2
```

Comment: More generalized answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5812853/973402; this solution is WAY faster than grep -f when you have a lot of patterns to check against

Answer (score 8):

This variant requires an `fgrep` with the `-f` option.  GNU grep (i.e. any Linux system, and then some) should work fine.

```
# Find occurrences of '#include' in file1.h
fgrep '#include' file1.h |
# Remove any identical lines from file2.h
fgrep -vxf - file2.h |
# Result is all lines not present in file1.h.  Out of those, extract #includes
fgrep '#include'
```

This does not require any sorting, nor any explicit temporary files.  In theory, `fgrep -f` could use a temporary file behind the scenes, but I believe GNU `fgrep` doesn't.

Comment: POSIX specifies `-f` so any POSIX compliant `grep` should have it.

Answer (score 6):

If the goal need not be accomplished with Bash alone (i.e., use of external programs is acceptable), then use `combine` from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
combine file1 not file2 > lines_in_file1_not_in_file2
```

Answer (score 2):

cat $file1 $file2 | grep '#include' | sort | uniq -u

Comment: This will list `#include` lines unique to file1 or file2.  I think that you want `cat $file1 $file1 $file2 | grep '#include' | sort | uniq -u`, with file1 repeated so that its `#include` lines are doubled and will then be filtered by the `uniq -u`.

Comment: And since `grep` can read multiple input files, you can use `grep -h` and do away with the (only moderately useless) `cat`.