# Shell line command Sorting command

Tags: shell

I have a Masters.txt (all records) and a New.txt file. I want to process New.txt against Masters.txt and output all the lines from New.txt that do not exist in Masters.txt

i'm not sure if this is something the sort -u command can do.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5812756/576875

Answer (score 2):

Sort both files first using `sort` and then use the `comm` command to list the lines that exist only in `new.txt` and not in `masters.txt`. Something like:

```
sort masters.txt >masters_sorted.txt
sort new.txt >new_sorted.txt
comm -2 -3 new_sorted.txt masters_sorted.txt
```

`comm` produces three columns in its output by default; column 1 contains lines unique to the first file, column 2 contains lines unique to the second file; column 3 contains lines common to both files. The `-2 -3` switches suppress the second and third columns.

Comment: shouldnt it be something like
comm -2 -3 new_sorted.txt masters_sorted.txt > new.txt

Comment: Well, if you want to store the result in ``new.txt`` (losing the contents of the old one), then yes, it should.

Comment: hmm is there a file list item limit... it doesn't seem to be work at. no output and not changes in either file

Comment: You don't need the temp files: `comm -23 <(sort masters.txt) <(sort new.ext)`

Answer (score 0):

see the linux comm command:

http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/08/linux-comm-command-brief-tutorial.html