# Remove lines from .txt gawk

Tags: awk, grep, gawk, gnuwin32

Okay so how do I remove lines from `new.txt` if they're in `tried.txt`,

For example, if `new.txt` contains 123 and `tried.txt` contains 123, so remove 123 from `in.txt` and output results to `new2.txt`.

Comment: Any chance you could put your description over multiple lines to make it easier to read?  Also, what have you done to try and solve this problem?

Comment: At the very minimum, you need to create some sample input files and the desired output: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Lines from File which appear in another File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -F -x -v -f tried.txt new.txt > new2.txt
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk "NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)" tried.txt new.txt > new2.txt
```

Any of the above commands should work for you. See:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28158/is-there-a-tool-to-get-the-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another
- [Remove Lines from File which appear in another File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)
- [Print lines from one file that are not contained in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812756/print-lines-from-one-file-that-are-not-contained-in-another-file%22)