# Compare 2 files and extract lines that are different

Tags: python, r, awk, comparison

I have 2 files for example :

file 1:

```
1 azer 4
2 toto 0
3 blabla 8
4 riri 9
5 coco 2
```

file 2:

```
1 azer 4
2 toto 0
3 blabla 8
```

I want to compare the two files, and if the lines in the file 2 are in the file 1, I want to remove those lines from the file 1. For example :

Output:

```
4 riri 9
5 coco 2
```

I tried this command but it show me only the similarities :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} $1 in a {print $0}' merge genotype.txt
```

Does any one know how to do this ? I tried it in awk but if it's possible to do this in R or python it's good too.

Comment: Why is this tagged with R? If you need R solution see this post: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871)

Comment: Would diff --suppress-common-lines suffice your needs?

Comment: Possible duplicate, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812756) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533)

Comment: Thank you i'm gonna look those post

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler solution in `grep`-

```
$cat file1
1 azer 4
2 toto 0
3 blabla 8
4 riri 9
5 coco 2

$cat file2
1 azer 4
2 toto 0
3 blabla 8
```

Try-

```
grep -vf file2 file1
```

Output-

```
4 riri 9
5 coco 2
```

Answer (score 1):

First, read file 2 lines as a `set` so testing is faster. Then iterate through lines of file 1 and write output file lines using a generator comprehension.

```
with open("file2.txt") as f: file2 = set(f)

with open("file1.txt") as fr, open("file3.txt","w") as fw:
    fw.writelines(l for l in fr if l not in file2)
```

- order preserved
- fast testing
- file 1 is never read fully in memory, but the chain of iterators read/write the files line by line

Answer (score 1):

```
# awk
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1

# comm
comm -23 file1 file2

# grep 
grep -Fvxf file2 file1
```

**Input**

```
$ cat file1
1 azer 4
2 toto 0
3 blabla 8
4 riri 9
5 coco 2

$ cat file2
1 azer 4
2 toto 0
3 blabla 8
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
4 riri 9
5 coco 2

$ comm -23 file1 file2
4 riri 9
5 coco 2

$ grep -Fvxf file2 file1
4 riri 9
5 coco 2
```