# How to remove all lines that are already contained in another line

Tags: file-io

Say I have a large file "done.txt"

Then I have another large file "post.txt"

I want to get rid all occurrence in post.txt that is already located in done.txt

I do not want to load all content of done.txt on the memory. How would I do so?

100% accuracy is not important.

Comment: What language/environment?  Shell?  PHP?  VBScript?  More detail, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Lines from File which appear in another File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 100% accuracy is not a requirement, you can hash all the lines in `done.txt` and keep in-memory a collection (array, list, whatever) of those hashes.

Then, process every line in `post.txt`. If the hash of that line matches one you already have, throw it away.

There'll be false positives (lines thrown away even though they're *not* in `done.txt`) but no false negatives.

Something like:

```
hash = []

for each line in done.txt:
    hashVal = makeHash (line)
    hash[hashVal] = true

for each line in post.txt:
    hashVal = makeHash (line)
    if not defined hash[hashVal]:
        print line
```

Or, if you want 100% accuracy with minimal in-memory storage, keep the hashes along with an collection of file offsets per hash.

If the line in `post.txt` doesn't match any hash, there's no possibility it's a duplicate, so you keep it.

If it *does* match a hash, then there's a *possibility* it's a duplicate. You then use the one or more file offsets for that hash entry to do a binary compare of the line being tested against the lines in `done.txt` (by reading in the actual lines). If a match is found there, it's a dupe so you toss away the line, otherwise you keep it.

That reduces in-memory storage (other than the lines from `post.txt` of course, but they're needed no matter what) to the hash-with-line-offsets collections and, at most, one line from `done.txt`, at the cost of some potential extra I/O.

But, since I'm not a big fan of "sub-100% accuracy", that's the way I'd probably go.

That would go something like:

```
hash = []

fileOffset = 0
for each line in done.txt:
    hashVal = makeHash (line)
    if not defined hash[hashVal]:
        hash[hashVal] = new list ()
    hash[hashVal].append (fileOffset)
    fileOffset = fileOffset + line.length ()

for each line in post.txt:
    hashVal = makeHash (line)
    printIt = true
    if defined hash[hashVal]:
        for each offset in hash[hashVal]:
            read chkLine from done.txt starting at offset
            if line == chkLine:
                printIt = false
    if printIt:
        print line
```

Comment: there is a problem with this. How do you read the actual line in a 5 GB file? The computer will read lines by lines one by one. That's O(n). The hash seems to be the right direction. Hash itself already reduce memory usage though.

Comment: @Jim, most languages will have a seek type of operation where you can seek first to a specific file offset. You simply seek to the stored offset then read a line. You don't need the entire 5G file in memory at once, just one line at a time. You also don't have to read lines 1 through 314158 if your only interest is in line 314159. You will know the offset from the hash entries. In fact the thing you _won't_ know is the line number, that information is not stored in the `done.txt` processing, nor is it needed.

Comment: oh.... Yes vb.net is what I am looking for. That's the language.