# Fast way of finding lines in one file that are not in another?

Tags: bash, grep, find, diff

I have two large files (sets of filenames). Roughly 30.000 lines in each file. I am trying to find a fast way of finding lines in file1 that are not present in file2.

For example, if this is **file1:**

```
line1
line2
line3
```

And this is **file2:**

```
line1
line4
line5
```

Then my **result/output** should be:

```
line2
line3
```

This works:

`grep -v -f file2 file1`

But it is very, very slow when used on my large files.

I suspect there is a good way to do this using `diff()`, but the output should be *just* the lines, nothing else, and I cannot seem to find a switch for that.

Can anyone help me find a fast way of doing this, using bash and basic Linux binaries?

**EDIT**: To follow up on my own question, this is the best way I have found so far using `diff()`:

```
diff file2 file1 | grep '^>' | sed 's/^>\ //'
```

Surely, there must be a better way?

Comment: you could try this if it is faster: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1 > out.txt`

Comment: without fast requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file

Comment: See also: [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-file-from-another-larger-file-in-bash).

Comment: Simple way with reduced tool set: `cat file1 file2 file2 | sort | uniq --unique`, see my answer below.

Comment: Or the more standard `| sort | uniq -u`.

Comment: Are the files sorted? Meaning, do you expect the equal lines to be in the same relative place?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

You can achieve this by controlling the formatting of the old/new/unchanged lines in GNU `diff` output:

```
diff --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format=""  file1 file2
```

The input files *should be sorted* for this to work. With `bash` (and `zsh`) you can sort in-place with process substitution `<( )`:

```
diff --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format="" <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

In the above *new* and *unchanged* lines are suppressed,  so only *changed* (i.e. removed lines in your case) are output. You may also use a few `diff` options that other solutions don't offer, such as `-i` to ignore case, or various whitespace options (`-E`, `-b`, `-v` etc) for less strict matching.

---

**Explanation**

The options `--new-line-format`, `--old-line-format` and `--unchanged-line-format` let you control the way `diff` formats the differences, similar to  `printf` format specifiers. These options format *new* (added), *old* (removed) and *unchanged* lines respectively. Setting one to empty "" prevents output of that kind of line.

If you are familiar with *unified diff* format, you can partly recreate it with:

```
diff --old-line-format="-%L" --unchanged-line-format=" %L" \
     --new-line-format="+%L" file1 file2
```

The `%L` specifier is the line in question, and we prefix each with "+" "-" or " ", like `diff -u`
(note that it only outputs differences, it lacks the `---` `+++` and `@@` lines at the top of each grouped change).
You can also use this to do other useful things like [number each line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34874/diff-output-line-numbers) with `%dn`.

---

The `diff` method (along with other suggestions `comm` and `join`) only produce the expected output with *sorted* input, though you can use `<(sort ...)` to sort in place. Here's a simple `awk` (nawk) script (inspired by the scripts linked-to in Konsolebox's answer) which accepts arbitrarily ordered input files, *and* outputs the missing lines in the order they occur in file1.

```pl
# output lines in file1 that are not in file2
BEGIN { FS="" }                         # preserve whitespace
(NR==FNR) { ll1[FNR]=$0; nl1=FNR; }     # file1, index by lineno
(NR!=FNR) { ss2[$0]++; }                # file2, index by string
END {
    for (ll=1; ll<=nl1; ll++) if (!(ll1[ll] in ss2)) print ll1[ll]
}
```

This stores the entire contents of file1 line by line in a line-number indexed array `ll1[]`, and the entire contents of file2 line by line in a line-content indexed associative array `ss2[]`. After both files are read, iterate over `ll1` and use the `in` operator to determine if the line in file1 is present in file2. (This will have have different output to the `diff` method if there are duplicates.)

In the event that the files are sufficiently large that storing them both causes a memory problem, you can trade CPU for memory by storing only file1 and deleting matches along the way as file2 is read.

```pl
BEGIN { FS="" }
(NR==FNR) {  # file1, index by lineno and string
  ll1[FNR]=$0; ss1[$0]=FNR; nl1=FNR;
}
(NR!=FNR) {  # file2
  if ($0 in ss1) { delete ll1[ss1[$0]]; delete ss1[$0]; }
}
END {
  for (ll=1; ll<=nl1; ll++) if (ll in ll1) print ll1[ll]
}
```

The above stores the entire contents of file1 in two arrays, one indexed by line number `ll1[]`, one indexed by line content `ss1[]`. Then as file2 is read, each matching line is deleted from `ll1[]` and `ss1[]`. At the end the remaining lines from file1 are output, preserving the original order.

In this case, with the problem as stated, you can also *divide and conquer* using GNU `split` (filtering is a GNU extension), repeated runs with chunks of file1 and reading file2 completely each time:

```
split -l 20000 --filter='gawk -f linesnotin.awk - file2' < file1
```

Note the use and placement of `-` meaning `stdin` on the `gawk` command line. This is provided by `split` from file1 in chunks of 20000 line per-invocation.

For users on non-GNU systems, there is almost certainly a GNU coreutils package you can obtain, including on OSX as part of the [Apple Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/features/) tools which provides GNU `diff`, `awk`, though only a POSIX/BSD `split` rather than a GNU version.

Comment: This does exactly what I need, in a tiny fraction of the time taken by the enormous grep. Thanks!

Comment: Found this [gnu manpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Line-Formats.html)

Comment: some of us aren't on gnu [OS X bsd here...] :)

Comment: @rogerdpack no probs: [Apple Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/features/) includes GNU `diff` (and more).

Comment: @mr.spuratic Excellent solution! One thing I noticed is that although it works, the shell returns exit code 1 instead of 0. Any idea why?

Comment: I assume you mean for `diff`: in general the input files will be different, 1 is returned by `diff` in that case. Consider it a bonus ;-) If you're testing in a shell script 0 and 1 are expected exit codes, 2 indicates a problem.

Comment: @mr.spuratic ah yeah, now I find it in the `man diff`. Thanks!

Comment: If you do not immediately see any output, swap file1 and file2 around.

Comment: Sorting `file2` scales worse than `grep -vf` so this answer is not a solution for large `file2`.

Answer (score 478):

The [comm](https://ss64.com/bash/comm.html) command (short for "common") may be useful `comm - compare two sorted files line by line`

```
#find lines only in file1
comm -23 file1 file2 

#find lines only in file2
comm -13 file1 file2 

#find lines common to both files
comm -12 file1 file2
```

The `man` file is actually quite readable for this.

Comment: Works flawlessly on OSX.

Comment: The requirement for sorted input should perhaps be highlighted.

Comment: `comm` also has an option to verify input is sorted, `--check-order` (which it seems to do anyway, but this option will cause it to error instead of continue). But to sort the files, simply do: `com -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` and so on

Comment: I was comparing a file that was generated in Windows against a file that was generated in Linux and it seemed like `comm` wasn't working at all. It took me a while to figure out that it's about the line endings: even lines that look identical are considered different if they have different line endings. The command `dos2unix` can be used to convert the CRLF line endings to LF only.

Comment: The caveat "this does not work for files with DOS line endings" would have to be added to more or less every single shell script answer. This is a common FAQ; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings

Answer (score 53):

Like konsolebox suggested, the posters grep solution

```
grep -v -f file2 file1
```

actually works great (faster) if you simply add the `-F` option, to treat the patterns as fixed strings instead of regular expressions. I verified this on a pair of ~1000 line file lists I had to compare. With `-F` it took 0.031 s (real), while without it took 2.278 s (real), when redirecting grep output to `wc -l`.

These tests also included the `-x` switch, which are necessary part of the solution in order to ensure totally accuracy in cases where file2 contains lines which match part of, but not all of, one or more lines in file1.

So a solution that does not require the inputs to be sorted, is fast, flexible (case sensitivity, etc) is:

```
grep -F -x -v -f file2 file1
```

This doesn't work with all versions of grep, for example it fails in macOS, where a line in file 1 will be shown as not present in file 2, even though it is, if it matches another line that is a substring of it. Alternatively you can [install GNU grep on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-install-and-use-gnu-grep-in-osx) in order to use this solution.

Comment: Yeah, it works but even with `-F` this doesn't scale well.

Comment: this is not that fast, I waited 5 minutes for 2 files of ~500k lines before giving up

Comment: actually, this way is still slower than comm way, because this one can handle unsorted files hence dragged down by unsorting, comm takes the advantage of sorting

Comment: @workplaylifecycle You need to add the time for sorting which may be the bottleneck for extremely large `file2`.

Comment: However, grep with the `-x` option apparently uses more memory. With a `file2` containing 180M words of 6-10 bytes my process got `Killed` on a 32GB RAM machine...

Comment: For anyone wondering: 100K lines is too much in practice for this solution.

Answer (score 27):

If you're short of "fancy tools", e.g. in some minimal Linux distribution, there is a solution with just `cat`, `sort` and `uniq`:

```
cat includes.txt excludes.txt excludes.txt | sort | uniq --unique
```

Test:

```
seq 1 1 7 | sort --random-sort > includes.txt
seq 3 1 9 | sort --random-sort > excludes.txt
cat includes.txt excludes.txt excludes.txt | sort | uniq --unique

# Output:
1
2
```

This is also *relatively* fast, compared to `grep`.

Comment: Note -- some implementations will not recognize the `--unique` option. You should be able to use the [standardized POSIX option](https://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/uniq/) for this: `| uniq -u`

Comment: In the example, where did the "2" come from?

Comment: @Niels2000, `seq 1 1 7` creates numbers from 1, with increment 1, until 7, i.e. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. And right there is your 2!

Comment: This does not work if includes.txt has any duplicates. `echo 2 >> includes.txt` after the `seq` calls makes `uniq` only output `1`

Answer (score 19):

Use `combine` from `moreutils` package, a sets utility that supports `not`, `and`, `or`, `xor` operations

```
combine file1 not file2
```

i.e give me lines that are in file1 but not in file2

OR give me lines in file1 minus lines in file2

**Note:** `combine` sorts and finds unique lines in both files before performing any operation but `diff` does not. So you might find differences between output of `diff` and `combine`.

So in effect you are saying

Find distinct lines in file1 and file2 and then give me lines in file1 minus lines in file2

In my experience, it's much faster than other options

Comment: This is the cleanest answer.  While all the other grep solutions and such are clever, this is a simple command built specifically for this purpose.

Comment: The best tool ever! Thanks for sharing this knowledge.

Answer (score 15):

whats the speed of as sort and diff?

```
sort file1 -u > file1.sorted
sort file2 -u > file2.sorted
diff file1.sorted file2.sorted
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the need to sort the files before doing diff. sort + diff is MUCH faster.

Comment: one liner ;-) diff <(sort file1 -u) <(sort file2 -u)

Answer (score 14):

This seems quick for me :

```
comm -1 -3 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) > output.txt
```

Comment: Awesome, but for target question just `comm file1 file2` because looks like sorted lists provided

Comment: Since comm has its own idea about what "sorted" means, you would have to suppress errors if both files are ordered the same, but not "sorted" according to comm's ideals. F.e. if both files are output of the same transformation but with different filters. In my case it was a list of all BTRFS subvolumes vs. list of read-only snapshots. Always in same order, but not exactly "sorted" lexically.

Comment: `comm` has a very standard understanding of what "sorted" means. Perhaps it helps if you understand the algorithm it's using. Because it can assume that the files are sorted, it never needs to peek ahead more than one line into each file and then keep on reading more lines from the one whose lines sort before the peeked-ahead line from the other file.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ join -v 1 -t '' file1 file2
line2
line3
```

The `-t` makes sure that it compares the whole line, if you had a space in some of the lines.

Comment: Like `comm`, `join` requires both input lines to be sorted on the field you are performing the join operation on.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Python:

```
python -c '
lines_to_remove = set()
with open("file2", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        lines_to_remove.add(line.strip())

with open("f1", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.strip() not in lines_to_remove:
            print(line.strip())
'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using of fgrep or adding -F option to grep could help. But for faster calculations you could use Awk.

You could try one of these Awk methods:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/grep-for-huge-files-826030/#post4066219

Comment: +1 This is the only answer which doesn't require inputs to be sorted. While apparently the OP was happy with that requirement, it is an unacceptable constraint in many real-world scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually do this is using the `--suppress-common-lines` flag, though note that this only works if your do it in side-by-side format.

`diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1.txt file2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

To test handling regexp metachars, substrings, spaces, case-insensitivity, otherwise-duplicate strings that only vary in case, and more than 2 input files we need some different sample input:

```
$ head input1 input2 input3
==> input1 <==
aAa
bBb
a.a
aa
BbB
AaA
ccc
ddd
E e E e

==> input2 <==
aaa
bb
b.b

==> input3 <==
ccc
dddd
e e e e
```

and then we can do this, using any grep:

```
$ grep -iFxv -f input2 -f input3 input1
bBb
a.a
aa
BbB
ddd
```

(or if you prefer `grep -iFxvf <(cat input2 input3) input1`) or any awk:

```
$ awk '
    { lc = tolower($0) }
    NR==FNR { a[lc] = ( lc in a ? a[lc] ORS : "" ) $0; next }
    { delete a[lc] }
    END { for ( lc in a ) print a[lc] }
' input1 input2 input3
a.a
bBb
BbB
ddd
aa
```

This was originally posted as an answer to [How to print the lines that do not occur in another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77910724/1745001) but was moved here as that question seems likely to be closed as a dup of this one and the above addresses cases that, best I can tell, are otherwise not covered by the existing answers here.

Answer (score 0):

`awk`-based solution sans any sorting :

```
awk '! (__[$+_] += NR == FNR)' FS='\n' file2 file1
```