# Get lines of file1 which are not in file2

Tags: linux

I have two long, but sorted files. How to get all lines of first file which are not in second file ?

*file1*

```
0000_aaa_b
0001_bccc_b
0002_bcc <------ file2 have not that line
0003_aaa_d
0006_xxx
...
```

*file2*

```
0000_aaa_b
0001_bccc_b
0003_aaa_d
0006_xxx
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast way of finding lines in one file that are not in another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what the `comm` command is for:

```
$ comm -3 file1 file2
0002_bcc
```

From `man comm`:

```
DESCRIPTION

   Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.

   With  no  options,  produce  three-column  output.  Column one contains
   lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to  FILE2,  and
   column three contains lines common to both files.

   -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)

   -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)

   -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

Comment: This only works for sorted files. Try `comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`.

Answer (score 3):

Just run a `diff` on them:

```
diff -c file1 file2
```

The `-c` (for "context") flag will only display the lines that are different, with two lines surrounding each line.