# Using grep to find difference between two big wordlists

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, grep, comm

I have one 78k lines .txt file with british words and a 5k lines .txt file with the most common british words. I want to sort out the most common words from the big list so that I have a new list with the not as common words.

I managed solve my problem in another matter, but I would really like to know, what I am doing wrong since this does not work.

I have tried the following:

```
//To make sure they are trimmed
cut -d" " -f1 78kfile.txt | tac | tac > 78kfile.txt
cut -d" " -f1 5kfile.txt | tac | tac > 5kfile.txt
grep -xivf 5kfile.txt 78kfile.txt > cleansed
//But this procedure apparently gives me two empty files.
```

If I run just the grep without cut first, I get words that I know are in both files.

I have also tried this:

```
sort 78kfile.txt > 78kfile-sorted.txt
sort 5kfile.txt > 5kfile-sorted.txt
comm -3 78kfile-sorted.txt 5kfile-sorted.txt
//No luck either
```

The two text files in case anyone wants to try for them selves:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dw3k8ragnvjcfgc/5k-most-common-sorted.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cvut5z2zp9qnmk/brit-a-z-sorted.txt

Comment: See the accepted answer for [this StackOverflow question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another

Comment: `cut -d" " -f1 78kfile.txt | tac | tac > 78kfile.txt` is almost certain to give you incomplete copy of `75kfile.txt` save for `5kfile.txt`. YOu need to save the result of pipelines to a separately named file, maybe `78kfile.tmp`. Good luck.

Comment: You can use vimdiff to see the difference between two files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After downloading your files, I noticed that (a) `brit-a-z-sorted.txt` has Microsoft line endings while `5k-most-common-sorted.txt` has Unix line endings and (b) you are trying to do whole-line compare (`grep -x`).  So, first we need to convert to a common line ending:

```
dos2unix <brit-a-z-sorted.txt >brit-a-z-sorted-fixed.txt
```

Now, we can use `grep` to remove the common words:

```
grep -xivFf  5k-most-common-sorted.txt brit-a-z-sorted-fixed.txt >less-common.txt
```

I also added the `-F` flag to assure that the words would be interpreted as a fixed strings rather than as regular expressions.  This also speeds things up.

I note that there are several words in the `5k-most-common-sorted.txt` file that are not in the `brit-a-z-sorted.txt`.  For example, "British" is in the common file but not the larger file.  Also the common file has "aluminum" while the larger file has only "aluminium".

**What do the grep options mean?**  For those who are curious:

`-f` means read the patterns from a file.

`-F` means treat them as fixed patterns, not regular expressions,

`-i` mean ignore case.

`-x` means do whole-line matches

`-v` means invert the match.  In other words, print those lines that do not match any of the patterns.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is very helpful. How did you notice the bloody ms line endings?

Comment: @r08o I noticed that `grep -w` (whole word pattern) worked but `grep -x` (whole line pattern) didn't.  That led me to suspect that there must be some issue with invisible characters in one of the files.