# Any way to make grep process faster?

Tags: performance, grep

I am using grep -v to parse strings which are not present in desired file from target file, however the process was taking too long (>12 hours) and was eventually killed by the machine without finishing the task.

The command I used:

```
grep -v -f desire.txt target.txt >> no_in_desire_file.txt
```

The `desire.txt` has 45502 strings; `target.txt` has 268101 strings.

Could someone shares with me your experience to speed up the grep process? I am not good in Python or Perl, unfortunately.

UPDATED:

The suggestion by @John1024 improved the speed of the `grep` process.

> If it contains just plain strings, then add the -F option for fixed
>   strings. This greatly speeds grep. –  John1024

Comment: How large in bytes are desire.txt, target.txt and no_in_desire_file.txt?

Comment: In many cases, import of a text file into a db of choice (such as postgresql) and designing an appropriate query is an only reasonable way to proceed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another - duplicate, as always. :)

Comment: Does `desire.txt` contain strings or regular expressions?  If it contains just plain strings, then add the `-F` option for fixed strings.  This greatly speeds `grep`.

Comment: @John1024, both text files contain strings like: comp100014_c0 comp0_c0_seq1. The length of the strings is different. Does -F works in this case?
The desire.txt has 45502 strings, target.tx has 268101 strings

Comment: @oakad, thanks for pointing out. I did searched around before posting this question, perhaps, I missed that thread. 
I read that post and tried with the diff solution, but, it did not work.

Comment: @KJLim Yes, `-F` would work for those strings.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for the suggestion. The grep -F works, but, the number of output is a bit strange. 
The desire.txt has 45502 strings, 
the target.txt has 268101 strings.
The total line of output is 217315. Hummm.....

Comment: @KJLim From that, I would conclude that you had some strings in `desire.txt` that matched more than one line in `target.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings that you are matching are not regular expressions, then a large speed-up is possible by specifying grep's `-F` option.

`grep` is capable of processing patterns in the form of very complex and powerful regular expressions.  Consider, for example:

```
$ echo mississippi | grep -E 'm(.*is)+.*i'
mississippi
```

In this case, `grep` looks for the letter `m` followed by one or more occurrences of a group consisting of any number of characters followed by `is`, all followed by any number of characters and then an `i`.  Computing such matches can be quite complicated.

In your case, however, you patterns are simple strings like:

```
comp100014_c0
comp0_c0_seq1
```

For these strings, we are looking for simple matches.  This requires no fancy computation.  To speed up `grep`, we can tell it that our strings are all simple. We do this by specifying the `-F` option.  In `man grep`, this feature is documented as:

> **-F, --fixed-strings**
>   Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed
>   strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F is
>   specified by POSIX.)