# How to print lines in one file that do not match lines in another *after transformation*

Tags: bash, comm

Please note, i understand how to output lines in one file that are not in another ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another)), my question is a little different.

In one file i have lines akin to

```
Андреев
Барбашев
Иванов
...
```

in a different file there are lines:

```
Барбашёв
Семёнов
...
```

Now. I need the lines from the second file, but only if you cannot find a line in the first where you substitute ё for е. For example `Барбашёв` should not display, because `Барбашев` is in the first.

If i do something like

```
comm -13 first.txt <(cat second.txt | sed 's/ё/е/g')
```

i get the correct lines, however, they have already been tranformed by that time, and it's unacceptable for what i'm trying to do.

In other words the output is:

```
Барбашев
...
```

While it should be

```
Барбашёв
...
```

Comment: What do you mean they are already transformed, please post full expected output.

Comment: @123 Sorry, i thought it was clear enough. But i've added the expected output.

Comment: `comm` works on sorted files. Have you tried sorting both files before using `comm`? You should not change anything else.

Comment: @GMichael Files are already sorted, that's not the issue.

Comment: what about `grep -vf file1 file2`? This uses `file1` to obtain the patterns.

Comment: Do it the other way round, convert `e` to `ё` ?

Comment: @123 That's not going to match all the time then, only on words with no `е` in them.

Comment: @v010dya I really don't think i understand what you want to do.

Comment: @123 It's ok. I think it might be not doable with regular tools, i'll write a 10 line C++ program i think, it'll be faster.

Comment: @v010dya oki doke, good luck.

Comment: I would consider using awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant:

"Now. I need the lines from the second file, but only if you cannot find a line in the first **when you substitute ё for е in the second file**."

instead of

"Now. I need the lines from the second file, but only if you cannot find a line in the first **where you substitute ё for е**."

Right?

Without using a cyrilic charset, this solution works:

file test.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

{
    if(NR==FNR)
        arr[$1]++;
    else {

        tmp=$1;
        gsub("t","e",tmp)

        if(!(tmp in arr))
            printf("%s\n", $1);
    }
}
```

Use:

```
$ ./test.awk file1 file2
```

If you substitute "t" -> "ё" this should also work imo. Maybe you can try.