# Awk to create new file from non existing first column

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

Let's say I have "File 1" with content as below:

```
    123|abc|def|
    456|ghi|jkl|
    789|mno|pqr|
```

And I have "File 2" with content as below:

```
    123|abc|def|
    456|ghi|jkl|
    789|mno|pqr|
    134|rst|uvw|
```

As you can see "134" does not exist on File 1, therefore, my shell script should create a File 3, that contains as follows.

```
    134|rst|uvw|
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please show us what you have tried already. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also you may just be looking for something as simple as `grep -vf file1 file2 > file3`

Comment: I just need to know what command is used best, not the whole code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast way of finding lines in one file that are not in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another)

Comment: yes, similar to my problem. Thanks

Comment: `sort file1 file2 | uniq -u >file3`?

Comment: @Cyrus, no that's problematic since it gives uniques from both files (though admittedly OP did not specify if that is a problem)

Comment: @Jedi yes, that is correct. Answer below is right and can be use for this problem, I've tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F\| 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a==0' file1 file2    # > file3
134|rst|uvw|
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F\| '     # field separator is |
NR==FNR {        # process first file
    a[$1]        # store the velue in the first field to hash a
    next         # next record
}                # below, processing the second file
$1 in a==0       # if first field is not found in the hash a, output the record
' file1 file2    # > file3 redirect to file3 if desired, else it's on your screen
```

Basically it stores the first field values of `file1` to hash `a` and while processing `file2` prints out the records where first field not found in the `a`. So it differs from `grep` solutions which compare the whole record, not just one field.