# Fast way of comparing lines in 2 files?

Tags: bash

I have two large files (sets of filenames). Roughly 30.000 lines in each file. I am trying to find a fast way of finding lines in file1 that are not present in file2.

For example, if this is file1:

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
```

And this is file2:

```
A=10
B=20
C=30
D=5
```

Then my result/output should be:

D=5

Since there is no D=Something in File1.

Comment: The first step is certainly to sort both of them.

Comment: You should decide whether this is a python or bash question. It can't be both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast way of finding lines in one file that are not in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another)

Comment: This has been marked as a duplicate, but it isn't a duplicate. The linked question is about finding matching whole lines. This question is about matching partial lines. Similar, but not a duplicate, and the answers to the other question need adapting to work here.

Comment: `awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1; next} !a[$1]' file1 file2 file3...` This will print the lines which are not in file1. You can supply any no of files after file1.

Comment: @Chris Lear Ah sorry :/. Based my comment on the question text. Don't have the privileges to cast a reopen vote though.

Answer (score 2):

You could read file 1 to a list, then read file 2 and for each entry check whether it is in that list.

```
filelist1 = []
with open(file1, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        filelist1.append(line.split('=')[0])

with open(file2, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.split('=')[0] not in filelist1:
            print(line)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: filelist1 = set() might be faster

Comment: @Aaron, you're right, not only faster but also more concise since you can just do `set1 - set2`

Comment: No sadly A=10 B=20 and C=30.So i cant do this.

Comment: So what exactly has to be equal? The "X=" part?

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve exactly, but you could add:

if line[:3] not in filelist1

Which would work in the scenario you show.

Comment: Actually what i want is the extra  D=something that file1 does not have while file 2 has.File 1 doesnt have any D=something.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to know that there is an 'A', 'B' and 'C' in both files, but the 'D' only is present in file 2?

Comment: yes correct.Thts correct jacob.

Answer (score 1):

This works for the example given, and is quite simple:

```
grep -v -F "`grep -o .*= file1`" file2
```

I tried it on an artificially-created 30000 line file, and it was fast.

It just uses `grep -o` to create a list of matches which is then fed into `grep -F` as fixed strings. Then `-v` is used to say 'show lines that don't match'

Some caveats:

- this is case sensitive, so `A=10` is different from `a=10`.
- there's an assumption that there is exactly one '=' sign on any line that's significant in file1, and that everything to the left of it (including spaces) is part of the check.
- **Probably a bug** if file1 contains A=10 and file2 contains AAA=10, A=10 will be found in file2, and therefore that line won't be reported. I'll try to rewrite the one-liner to fix this bug

Another option, which is simpler and actually nicer

```
join -t= -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

This one requires file1 and file2 to be sorted first, but doesn't show the bug that the `grep` version above shows. It's also probably faster (I haven't really checked). The other caveats above still apply.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work but it would only give you "D", not the complete line - depends on what you need downstream and what exactly your files look like. Also, as mentioned by Aaron, it should be quite fast.

```
with open("path/to/file1") as f1, open("path/to/file2") as f2:
    s1 = set(x.split("=")[0] for x in f1)
    s2 = set(x.split("=")[0] for x in f2)
    result = s2-s1
```

If you need the full line:

```
with open("path/to/file1") as f1, open("path/to/file2") as f2:
    s1 = set(x.split("=")[0] for x in f1)
    result = [x for x in f2 if not x.split("=")[0] in s1]
```

Comment: I need the full line.

Comment: @mutatedzombie ok, then it's a tad more complicated.