# How to print the lines that do not occur in another file?

Tags: awk

I have two files, `input1` and `input2`. I want to do the following: for any line `L` in `input1`, check if `input2` contains at least one line whose text is equal to `L`; if `input2` does not contain such a line, print `L` to the output file.

For example, `input1`:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

And `input2`:

```
aaa
ccc
```

The expected output is

```
bbb
```

My code is

```
gawk -F ';' 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1;}; 
    {if ( FILENAME == "input2" ) 
    {a[$0] = 1};
    if ( (FILENAME == "input1" ) && !( $0 in a))  
    {print($0) > "path/to/output"}}' path/to/input2 path/to/input1
```

But this code does not work: the program produces no output at all. Why? How to fix the code to obtain the expected output?

**EDIT**

My question is about a solution that uses only GAWK (and specifically, why the given code did not work), so it is definitely not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another).

Comment: If you don't mind using other tools, consider `comm -23 input1 input2`. You may need to sort the files (e.g. `<(sort input1)` in bash).

Comment: Perhaps try `gawk -F ';' 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} {if (!($0 in a)) {print > "path/to/output"}}' path/to/input2 path/to/input1`? Re https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-are-nr-and-fnr-and-what-does-nr-fnr-imply

Comment: Your code works as expected for me: See [here](https://replit.com/@msankrit/DarkmagentaRealSystemresource#main.sh)

Comment: @jared_mamrot: this code works, but I am interested in how to generalize it to work with more than two files. The `NR==FNR` condition will only work for the first file.

Comment: @mandy8055: I do not know why, but it does not work for me (I tested in two different devices, in the old Cygwin and the new MSYS2).

Comment: Your objection to `NR==FNR` is puzzling. How exactly would it make sense to generalize this to multiple files? If the stuff to check for is in more than one file then `cat those files | awk 'NR==FNR { ... }' - finalfile`. If you want to check for the same lines in more than one file then `NR==FNR` will continue to work fine; it only special-cases the first input file.

Comment: _how to generalize it to work with more than two files._ : would you like to print lines in `input1` that do not occur in any other input files?

Comment: @tripleee: I was interested in a single-pass, GAWK-only solution, without using external commands to concatenate files (such as `cat`).

Comment: @Grobu: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: The question is still, generalize how? You can easily switch the order of the arguments to achieve that if it's only for your own personal use, and then `NR==FNR` will, again, continue to work fine.

Comment: But then the actual question here also only asks about two files, and does not explain how or why the search should be case-insensitive. Some of the solutions can easily be modified to ignore case (`grep -i`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generalized version with `NR==FNR` which works for an arbitrary number of file names.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0] = 1; next }
  $0 in a { delete a[$0] }
  END { for (line in a) print line }' importantlines file2 file3 file4
```

It turns around and reads the lines from the first file into memory, then successively removes any which are found in any of the other files, and then in the `END` block prints whatever remains. The order will be essentially random (but it's not hard to fix that if you want the lines in the input order; just store the line number in the array, and sort on that).

Comment: I have never seen the `for (...) if print line` construction before. Can you please explain the meaning of this syntax?

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed now. I had started on a slightly more ambitious solution to keep the lines sorted and forgot to remove one piece of it.

Comment: “a slightly more ambitious solution to keep the lines sorted” — that would be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason why the code in the question did not work. It is because I thought that the FILENAME variable stores only the filename without full path. It turns out that in Cygwin the FILENAME is `"full/path/to/input.extension"`, not just `input.extension`. My code works when I edit the `FILENAME == "input"` conditions accordingly.

Comment: This is definitely not specific to Cygwin or Windows; that is by definition what `FILENAME` contains.

Comment: According to Section 7.5.2 of the [GAWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables-That-Control-awk), `FILENAME` is “the name of the current input file”, but I did not know the definition of the word “name”. By the way, I have no idea why I wrote “without extension.” in the first edition of this answer. I mean, `input.extension` was my understanding of the word “name”.

Comment: That would be weird, though. But I guess if you are on Windows, you _expect_ weird.

Comment: Yes, now I see how unexplainably wrong I was. Had `FILENAME` not store the full path, the program would not even be able to work with files from different directories!

Answer (score 1):

A code suggestion to print lines in `input1` that do not occur in other input files:

```
BEGIN { LastFile = ARGV[length(ARGV) - 1] }

FILENAME != LastFile { Seen[$0] = 1 }

FILENAME == LastFile {
  do { if(! ($0 in Seen)) print $0 }
  while( getline )
  }
```

You would invoke it with `input1` as the last argument, e.g.

```
awk -f script.awk input3 input2 input1
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple task for `grep`:

```
$ grep --help
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Search for PATTERNS in each FILE.
...
  -v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
  -f, --file=FILE           take PATTERNS from FILE
...
```

Test files:

```
$ cat f1
aaa
bbb
ccc

$ cat f2
aaa
ccc
```

Greping:

```
$ grep -vf f2 f1
bbb
```