# How to compute overlap time of two arrays of (price, time) elements

Tags: language-agnostic, intervals

I'm having a hard time coming up with an algorithm at work that essentially computes the following

> Suppose you two arrays. Each element in the array contains price and time. Each array is sorted in ascending order of time. e.g., array1 = [(10, 1), (5, 2), (7, 4)] means that price = 10 from time = 1 to 2, price = 5 from time = 2 to 4 and price = 7 at time = 4. Compute the total overlap time of the 2 arrays in which the absolute price difference is <= 10.

So just to give an example, suppose we have

```
array1 = [(10, 1), (5, 2), (7, 4)]

array2 = [(19, 0), (6, 2), (23, 4)]
```

The overlap time here is 3. From time = 1 to time = 4 (non-inclusive), the difference is <= 10. For the time interval [0, 1), the price difference is undefined and does not contribute to the overlap time. For the interval [1, 2), the price difference is < 10 and ditto for [2, 4). So they have a price diff < 10 for the interval [1, 4), hence the answer is 3.

(It's a lot easier to visualize if you plot it on a x-y plot and see when the 2 lines have a difference in y of <= 10 for the same x value).

I've tried several algorithms of looping through the intervals, but always manage to miss some edge cases. Admittedly, I'm not good at these kind of interval merging problems (I think there's a specific word that describes this class of problems but I can't recall it). What are some foolproof ways to solve this?

I feel like there's a particular way I should be thinking of this problem that would make the implementation trivial, and evidently I'm not thinking about it that way.

Comment: There is no time=7 in your example arrays. (There also seems to be a typo or something in the assignment's example.) Do you mean the difference between the two arrays in the given time interval?

Comment: @tripleee Sorry, I swapped the time and price in my head. I think I corrected the OP to accurately reflect the examples provided

Comment: @tripleee Right, I mean in the given time interval. Let me add some more details to make it clearer

Comment: Would the `comm` algorithm for traversing sorted data from two sources perhaps be what you are looking for? Your time intervals are, by definition, sorted sequences. I explained it just yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another/64521377#comment137361138_64521377

Comment: (Your example and the one in the assigment still talk about a time 7 which isn't in the data.)

Comment: So if I understand your example correctly the desired answer is 3, because there is no attestation for time=0 in the first series and so the overlap starts at 1 and ends at (as in, just before) 4 where the difference becomes too large.

Comment: @tripleee I briefly looked into the comm wiki page, and I think something like that would work, though the issue I'm having is translating that to actual code. This is one of the problems that seemed a lot easier in my head than actually implementing it

Comment: This should be bog-standard merge, as seen in e.g. mergesort. It is unclear what your problem is. Please show your attempt.

Comment: Can you clarify what happens if the last prices of both arrays are within the threshold? It would mean that on a timeline, both prices will last without end, and so you'd logically have an eternal period where the price difference is within the threshold.

Comment: @trincot The example I provided was over simplified, but you can think of each array as an infinite stream, so there's no end to the data that's coming in in my actual use case. For the problem here, let's just assume that the last entry is its own end point, i.e., (7,4) has price = 4 from time = 4 to time = 4 (0 seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to visit the entries from the two input arrays in sorted order (by their time): whenever you can select from either array, choose the item with the least time, and move to the next item in that selected array, so in the next iteration *that* item can be compared by its time.

Once you have implemented that traversal, you can traverse items until you have a price from both sources, and compare the differences as the traversal continues.

Here is an implementation in Python:

```py
# Merge two sorted price-evolution lists in sorted order
def merged(list1, list2):
    iters = (iter(list1), iter(list2))
    val = [next(iters[0], None), next(iters[1], None)]
    while val[0] is not None or val[1] is not None:
        i = val[0] is None or val[1] is not None and val[0][1] > val[1][1]
        yield i, val[i]
        val[i] = next(iters[i], None)

def overlap_time(list1, list2, maxdiff):
    prices = {}  # To keep track of last price per source-list
    result = 0
    # Iterate the price change events in chronological order
    for source, (price, time) in merged(list1, list2):
        # Do we have prices from both source lists and are they close?
        if len(prices) == 2 and abs(prices[0] - prices[1]) <= maxdiff:
            result += time - prevtime
        prices[source] = price
        prevtime = time
    return result
```

Example call:

```py
list1 = [(10, 1), (5, 2), (7, 4)]
list2 = [(19, 0), (6, 2), (8, 4), (28, 8)]
print(overlap_time(list1, list2, 10))  # 3
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to visit the 2 arrays in order of increasing time, but I seem to miss edge cases with my (various) implementations. Let me see if you code passes all my edge cases

Comment: hmm I think doing the initial merge simplifies the overlap algorithm. the main issue I was having previously is I never did the initial merge step, and instead I tried to implement overlap_time by using 2 pointers (1 for each of the 2 lists)

Comment: with your overlap approach, how much more work would it be if you don't do the initial merge and tried to operate directly on the 2 list streams as I initially tried?

Comment: I found that separating the logic for the merge from finding overlap times made it easier to think about it, and led to cleaner code. I guess you also noticed that the merging phase can be done with streams-like patterns. Here, in Python, I've used iterables as input for that merge, which means they could be iterators whose entries only get consumed when they are needed. And so the execution of the two functions goes in "tandem", where in each iteration of the loop in `overlap_time` an iteration is made in `merge`. If the inputs are iterators, the input is only needed when it is "their turn".

Comment: i tried merging it together, and still struggled to get something clean and 100% accurate like what you have. I am doing it in C++ so it's a little harder, but I had trouble thinking along the same lines as you did in terms of how to process each element in merged