# Need help on awk command

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, scripting

1. I have a file `file1` which contains various strings. These strings have to be used with regular expression.
2. I have a another file which will be updated in realtime. 
   `tail -f <filename>` will provide the continuous output.
3. My requirement is to skip the strings present in `file1` and show the rest of output in `file2`.

For example: `file1` has the content below

```
Result of operation: got a 2 bytes
49.53.4F.30.31.36.30.30.30.30.31.35.30.32.31.30
Processing Event
```

Note: to match line 2 in `file1`, I have to use a regular expression.

File2 has content that will be file1 + X.
So, in my output only X (the extra lines) should be displayed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Lines from File which appear in another File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)

Comment: Actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file is a better duplicate.  Sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 1):

To display additions to `file2` in real time while skipping any lines which match a regular expression in `file1`, use:

```
tail -f file2 | grep -vf file1
```

Comment: What is I have file3,file4.. in addition to file2 and I want to show the common ouptut.
please help

Comment: The question, as it currently is written, says nothing about a `file3` or a `file4`.  What does it mean that you want "to show the common output"?  Do you only want to display lines from `file2` if they are also in `file3` and also in `file4`?   Or what?

Comment: yes. 
file1 has list of master strings to be checked.
file2,file3,file4 can contain strings from file1.

I want to list everything unmatched output from file2,3,4 into single one. 

sorry, did not give you this info earler.

Comment: Also to add to this answer, if you want to pass the grep output to another piped command, you may likely need to add `--line-buffered` option to `grep` command.

Comment: Hello anish, 
Can you explain me more on how to add a --line-buffered option ?
an example would be help a lot