# BASH ISSUE : Compare Two Different Larger Set Text Files and Get the Matching IP address

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have two TXT files , 1.txt has 11,000 IPs and 2.txt has 1 Million IPs. I want to match **1.txt** against **2.txt** ( 1 million IPs) and get the matching ones.

```
#1.txt
1,1.1.1.1
2,2.2.2.2
3,3.3.3.3
.........

#2.txt
51.51.6.10
12.10.25.16
1.3.50.55
0.0.0.0
6.6.6.6
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
5.5.5.5
6.6.6.6
7.7.7.7
20.200.100.30
Like wise 1 Million lines of IPs.......

Matching Result :
1,1.1.1.1
2,2.2.2.2
```

1. I tried doing  `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}($2 in a)' 2.txt 1.txt`,It gives me the exact answer for the smaller subset(Test Runs). But checking against the original files 11,000 against 1 Million IPs,It's returning me all the IPs which is in `1.txt`.
2. Tried `sed -n -f <(sed 's|.*|/,&$/p|' 2.txt) 1.txt`, Process is automatically killed.
3. Tried, `comm -23 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt`,Again returning all the IPs from 1.txt.

Not sure with the issue on where i'm making mistakes / matching against 1 million IPs is not possible using sed , awk , comm or any ? Can some one help me on suggesting what will be the issue ?

```
Reference Used : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file
```

Comment: The awk command won't change how it works for larger sets of data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption #1**: files are sorted as show in your original question

**Assumption #2**: ip addresses are unique

If you want just the IP addresses:

```
$ comm -12 <(cut -d, -f2 1.txt) 2.txt 
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

If you want the whole line in 1.txt:

```
$ comm -12 <(cut -d, -f2 1.txt) 2.txt  | while read ip ; do grep $ip 1.txt ; done
1,1.1.1.1
2,2.2.2.2
```

**UPDATE**

If my Assumption#1 is not valid, then you have to sort 1.txt and 2.txt in-line.

This is the solution to get just common IP addresses:

```
$ comm -12 <(cut -d, -f2 1.txt |sort) <(sort 2.txt) 
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

and this will show the full line from 1.txt:

```
$ comm -12 <(cut -d, -f2 1.txt |sort) <(sort 2.txt) | while read ip ; do grep $ip 1.txt ; done
1,1.1.1.1
2,2.2.2.2
```

I also made a quick test on my small MacBook Air using 1ML IPs in 1.txt and 0.5ML IPs in 2.txt. It takes 19 seconds if files have to be sorted.

Comment: When getting the whole line in 1.txt,I'm getting status as comm : file 2 is not in sorted order. comm : file 2 is not in sorted order. ? But i have sorted the files (#sort nu) already.

Comment: I tried it again @mauro, Just empty results when redirected to a file and checked. I'm running it in ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Comment: @Arun. Check your input files... `head -n 5 1.txt | od-c` and similar for 2.txt

Comment: Checking against #1.txt @mauro,I got     :                                                                                       0000000    3   ,   5   0   .   1   6   .   2   2   4   .   1   0   7  \n
0000020    5   ,   9   5   .   1   7   0   .   7   2   .   1   1   3  \n
0000040    6   ,   2   1   2   .   8   4   .   6   6   .   1   9  \n   7
0000060    ,   2   1   3   .   1   7   9   .   5   4   .   1   1  \n   9
0000100    ,   1   1   8   .   1   2   7   .   4   5   .   4   5  \n    
0000117

Comment: checking against #2.txt @mauro i got this : 0000000    1   .   5   2   .   3   5   .   1   6      \n   1   .   2   3
0000020    4   .   5   1   .   2   3   0      \n   4   .   2   6   .   6
0000040    7   .   1   1   2      \n   4   .   2   6   .   2   0   9   .
0000060    2   5   0      \n   4   .   5   3   .   1   1   1   .   3   3
0000100       \n
0000102

Comment: @Arun. They seems ok. The only explanation for empty results is that there are no common IPs. Check with a "controlled test env" where you know in advance the expected result.

Comment: Will check once again @mauro . I tried to create a separate  database tables and wrote a JOIN query to compare the IPs in one table (1.txt) to match against another (2.txt). Frankly speaking the DB crashed to render matches. So i wanted to find a way in bash to find it. Anyway thanks for your help  indeed ! will check it under "controlled test env "