# Mac OS terminal solution to remove from a textfile lines from another textfiles

Tags: macos, terminal

I work in SEO and sometimes I have to manage lists of domains to be considered for certain actions in our campaigns. On my iMac, I have 2 lists, one provided for consideration - `unfiltered.txt` - and another that has listed the domains I've already analyzed - `used.txt`. The one provided for consideration, the new one (`unfiltered.txt`), looks like this:

```
site1.com
site2.com
domain3.net
british.co.uk
england.org.uk
auckland.co.nz
... etc
```

List of domains that needs to be used as a filter, to be eliminated (`used.txt`) - looks like this.

```
site4.org
site5.me
site6.co.nz
gland.org.uk
kland.co.nz
site7.de
site8.it
... etc
```

Is there a way to use my OS X terminal to remove from unfiltered.txt all the lines found in used.txt? Found a software solution that partially solves a problem, and, aside from the words from used.txt, eliminates also words containing these smaller words. It means I get a broader filter and eliminate also domains that I still need.

For example, if my unfiltered.txt contains a domain named `fogland.org.uk` it will be automatically eliminated if in my used.txt file I have a domain named `gland.org.uk`.

Files are pretty big (close to 100k lines). I have pretty good configuration, with SSD, i7 7th gen, 16GB RAM, but it is unlikely to let it run for hours just for this operation.

... hope it makes sense.

TIA

Comment: Duplicate of [Remove Lines from File which appear in another File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `awk`. You pass both files to `awk`. Whilst parsing the first file, where the current record number across all files is the same as the record number in the current file, you make a note of each domain you have seen. Then, when parsing the second file, you only print records that correspond to ones you have not seen in the first file:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$0]++;next} !seen[$0]' used.txt unfiltered.txt
```

**Sample Output for your input data**

```
site1.com
site2.com
domain3.net
british.co.uk
england.org.uk
auckland.co.nz
```

`awk` is included and delivered as part of macOS - no need to install anything.

Comment: thank you, but is this faster then grep for large files?

Comment: Your question didn't mention speed was an issue and I don't know how big your files are, nor how fast your disk is - please just try it.

Comment: Alright. Your solution is given in several other pages on stackoverflow. The main problem everybody talks about when it comes to awk is speed. Tried it few days ago, it is the simplest solution but that's about it. Speed is a factor, file size is another factor. I will add speed and file size to the specs. Thanks again.

Comment: I just tested with 100,000 lines in each file in under 1 second.

Comment: 1,000,000 lines in each file takes 2.6 seconds.

Comment: "used.txt" 100k and "unfiltered.txt" 100k as well? I mean did you filted 100k entries with another 100k lines file? Because I've tried it a few days ago and I had to stop it after a few minutes. If you are right, that HAS to be the answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used

```
grep -v -F -f expunge.txt filewith.txt > filewithout.txt
```

to do this. When "expunge.txt" is too large, you can do it in stages, cutting it into manageable chunks and filtering one after another:

```
cp filewith.txt original.txt

and loop as required:
    grep -v -F -f chunkNNN.txt filewith.txt > filewithout.txt
    mv filewithout.txt filewith.txt
```

You could even do this in a pipe:

```
 grep -v -F -f chunk01.txt original.txt |\
 grep -v -F -f chunk02.txt original.txt |\
 grep -v -F -f chunk03.txt original.txt \
 > purged.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `comm`. I haven't got a mac here to check but I expect it will be installed by default.  Note that both files must be sorted. Then try:

`comm -2 -3 unfiltered.txt used.txt`

Check the man page for further details.

Comment: Works with grep, but it doesn't handle well large files. Found grep -Fvx -f used.txt unfiltered.txt >final.txt && mv final.txt unfiltered.txt. I assume comm wouldn't help either when working with 100k lines in each file. What does "sorted" mean?

Comment: I expect `comm` would be much faster than `grep` at this task. I just tested using 2 files with 100K lines and `comm` took about 0.2s on my laptop on its first run. I tried with `grep` but it hadn't finished after a minute so I killed it.

Comment: "sorted" means to be arranged in order. There are different ordering systems but in this case which you use doesn't matter as long as both files use the same one. A common sorting order is "alphabetical". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting

Comment: Ah - I just saw you want to match substrings. `comm` won't do that. I can't think of a better tool to use than grep - though maybe if you have multiple cores some divide and conquer might help.

Comment: I'm gonna put a bounty on this in 1 day. Thanks for your efffort.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is a common command line tool for this - I expect fro any decent performance you will need an implementation of quicksearch or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `comm` and process substitution to do everything in one line:

```
comm -23 <(sort used.txt) <(sort unfiltered.txt) > used_new.txt
```

P.S. tested on my Mac running OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan)