# For each line L of a file file1.txt, remove the line of the file composer.json that contains L

Tags: shell, sed, diff

I have a file **file1.txt** that contains almost forty lines, each line contains a package name.
I have another file **composer.json** that contains hundreds of packages. I need to remove all packages of my **file1.txt** from **composer.json**

> file1.txt

```
remote5/package40
remote1/package1
remote4/package3
...
remote1/package2
```

> Current composer.json

```
{
    "name": "name/project_name",
    "description": "sf project blabla",
    ...
    "config": {
        "installer-paths: {
            "remote34/package345",
            "remote21/package345",
            "remote123/package345",
            "remote384/package345",
            "remote444/package345",
            ...
            "remote1/package1",
            "remote1/package2",
            "remote4/package3",
            ...
            "remote5/package40",
         }
     }
}
```

As you can see, the files are different, so I can't use this solution [Remove Lines from File which appear in another File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)

> Wanted composer.json

```
{
    "name": "name/project_name",
    "description": "sf project blabla",
    ...
    "config": {
        "installer-paths: {
            "remote34/package345",
            "remote21/package345",
            "remote123/package345",
            "remote384/package345",
            "remote444/package345",
            ...
         }
     }
}
```

Here is the command I've been trying so far

```
for i in `cat file1.txt`; do echo $i && sed -i '/$i/d' composer.json; done
```

This doesn't change **composer.json**. However the command below works

```
sed -i '/remote4\/package3/d' composer.json
```

**UPDATE**

```
grep -Fvxf file1.txt composer.json
```

The output is exactly **composer.json**'s content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Lines from File which appear in another File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)

Comment: @Sundeep I updated my question

Comment: you can still re-purpose on of the answers(https://stackoverflow.com/a/32267899/4082052) to `grep -vFf file1.txt composer.json`

Comment: Omit the `x` from the `grep -Fvf file1.txt compser.json` - it means exact match.  Your JSON lines have leading blanks and quotes around the values, so they aren't exact matches.  The `-F` means 'no metacharacters' (which means a different form of 'exact match', and the one you want).

Comment: `"installer-paths` - the right double quote is missed. Also this `{
            "remote34/package345",
            "remote21/package345",
            "remote123/package345",
            "remote384/package345",
            "remote444/package345",
            ...
         }` is invalid JSON notation. Update your `composer.json` to make it valid JSON

Comment: @smarber, actually, I'm already observing the expected result on my local machine. It only remains for you to provide a proper/valid `composer.json`

Comment: in `grep` the use of `-x` is looking for exact line match, which you don't have due to various formatting differences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `grep`

```
grep -Fvf <(sed 's/.*/"&",/' file1.txt) composer.json
```

decorate your search keys with the json format and look for fixed string match.

Comment: This works like a charm! However, could you explain the **<(....)** or provide a reference because I'm not familiar with ?

Comment: It's called process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your composer.json is not valid.
With your data, you can try

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {b=$0;sub("[^\"]*\"","");sub("\"[^\"]*$","");if(!($0 in a))print b}' file1.txt composer.json
```