# How can I delete the lines in a text file that exits in another text file

Tags: bash

How can I delete the lines in a text file that exits in another text file? Like sorting, I pretty much want to clear that text file deleting the strings (lines) that are in the other file.

I try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
B=badwords.txt
while read line; do
grep -v "$line" allwords.txt > $$ && mv $$ goodwords.txt
done < $B
```

Comment: You can use sed or awk. sed -i /$line/d file_to_delete_lines.tx

Comment: Is not working.

Comment: See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file

Comment: decision criteria: files sorted/unsorted? need to preserve order? file sizes?

Comment: Unsorted, no , 200 kb

Comment: `grep -vxFf badwords words > goodwords` should be good enough for you, but check the links suggested above for other solutions.