# How can I give all words from one file to 'tr' for searching and deleting in text from another file?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

How to give all words from one file to `tr` for searching and deleting in text from another file?

For example, I have a file `vocabulary.txt` and `loveStroty.txt`. I'm trying to delete all words that in are vocabulary from love Story.

```
$ voc="one free" #files look like this strings
$ love="one two free four"
$ tr "$voc" '' <<< $love
```

Example for output (doesn't matter if it is with separators or with new line separated):

```
two
four
```

Comment: `tr` isn't the right tool for this; it's purpose is to replace (or remove) individual characters. `tr -d 'abc'` is the same as `tr -d 'cba'` – it has no notion of character sequences.

Comment: Also, the second set can't be empty if you're not truncating the first set. To remove characters, you have to use `tr -d` – but again, you don't want to use `tr` in the first place.

Comment: You say you have two files, but your example uses strings instead of files. What do the two files look like? One word per line?

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, all text in files like this strings. What I should do instead tr?

Comment: No linebreaks? One super long line? Or not? What's the desired output?

Comment: @BenjaminW, It possible to make it with separators or linebreaks if with it will more ease to solve

Comment: You mean you want to remove common elements in both lists? Use `comm`.

Comment: It really matters what the input and the output exactly look like. For example, if the input files are both lists, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4366533/3266847); if they are space separated, it's another problem. It's unclear what exactly you want.

Comment: @BenjaminW. It's like two one line stings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your input files look like this:

```
$ cat lovestory.txt
one two free four
$ cat vocabulary.txt
one free
```

In Bash, I can then use `grep`, process substitution and `tr` to remove every word from `lovestory.txt` that exists in `vocabulary.txt` like this:

```
$ grep -vFxf <(tr ' ' '\n' < vocabulary.txt) <(tr ' ' '\n' < lovestory.txt)
two
four
```

`tr ' ' '\n' < file` replaces every space in `file` with a newline; `grep -vFx` removes matches of complete lines (fixed strings, no regular expressions).

Answer (score 1):

If files are not big enough, you could give `sed` utility a try:

```
# Define the text which replaces the searched words
replace="<Replacement string here>"

for word in $(cat /path/to/<file_containing_words>); do
  sed -i "s/${word}/${replace}/g" <file_to_be_replaced>
done
```

So, for your specific example

```
replace=""

for word in $(cat /path/to/voc); do
  sed -i "s/${word}/${replace}/g" /path/to/love
done
```

Comment: how I cat replace `/path/to/love` and `path/to/voc` with some stings?

Comment: Both set of words are in individual files, right ? (Atleast that's what I understood from your question above). You can just replace `/path/to/voc` and `/path/to/love` with respective absolute file paths on your system

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' vocabulary.txt lovestory.txt
two
four
```