# Remove line in a file in similar found in a list

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have  a file "selected_files.log" containing paths (a couple thousand lines) and I have a exclusion file "exclusion.txt" containing path and extensions I don't want to see in my selected_files.log

I have been trying with grep and sed, with no luck
this is my last search. anybody help? thanks

```
lines=$(cat exclusion.txt)
for x in "$lines";
do
    grep -v "$x" "selected_files.log" > new_file.log
    echo "x is $x"
    #sed `/$x/d` -i "selected_files.log" 
done
```

Comm -23 doesn't work because files aren't sorted.
I've tried with "/"$x"/d" -i but no luck : unterminated address regex

exemples of what my files contain
selected_files.log

```
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/001584.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/00284.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/0058244.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/A12/external.log
/mnt/user/system/data/A12/internal.log
/mnt/user/system/input/system_run.sh 
/mnt/user/system/input/user.sh
/mnt/user/system/output/results.dt 
/mnt/user/david/test/test.sh
/mnt/user/david/prod/bdd.bkp
/mnt/user/system/old_bkp.tmp
/mnt/user/system/output/test space/test.tmp
```

exclusion.txt

```
external.log
/mnt/user/system/input/
david
.tmp
```

result wanted:

```
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/001584.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/00284.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/0058244.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/A12/internal.log
/mnt/user/system/output/results.dt
```

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/how-to-remove-the-lines-which-appear-on-file-b-from-another-file-a
Better than sed

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: may be you are quoting sed with ' thats why variable is not expanding. use sed "/"$x"/d" -i

Comment: see my answer for working for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Haru, my solution was a mix of all.

```
lines="$(cat "exclusion.txt")"
IFS=$'\n'
for x in `echo "$lines"`; 
do echo "x is $x"; 
grep -v "$x" "selected_files.log" > new_file.log; 
sed "/"$(echo "${x//\//\\\/}")"/d" "selected_files.log" -i; 
done
unset IFS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Fvxf exclusion.txt selected_files.log >> tmp && cat tmp > selected_files.log
```

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' exclusion.txt selected_files.log >> tmp && cat tmp > selected_files.log
```

```
gawk -i inplace 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' exclusion.txt selected_files.log
```

Note : It will edit inplace selected_files.log but also wipes the exclusion.txt

Seems like for loop is causing problem.
Try

```
cat exclusion.txt | while read f; do sed "/^${f//\//\\\/}$/d" selected* -i; done
```

Updated for loop working

cat selected_files.log

```
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/001584.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/00284.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/0058244.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/A12/external.log
/mnt/user/system/data/A12/internal.log
/mnt/user/system/input/system_run.sh 
/mnt/user/system/input/user.sh
/mnt/user/system/output/results.dt 
/mnt/user/david/test/test.sh
/mnt/user/david/prod/bdd.bkp
/mnt/user/system/old_bkp.tmp
```

cat exclusion.txt

```
external.log
/mnt/user/system/input/
david
.tmp
```

```
IFS=$'\n' && for f in `cat exclusion.txt`; do sed "/^"${f//\//\\\/}"$/d" selected_files.log -i; done
```

OR

```
lines="$(cat exclusion.txt)"
for x in `echo "$lines"`; 
do  grep -v "$x" "selected_files.log" > new_file.log; 
echo "x is $x"; 
sed "/^"$(echo "${x//\//\\\/}")"$/d" selected_files.log -i; 
done
```

cat selected_files.log

```
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/001584.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/00284.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/S97/0058244.bkp
/mnt/user/system/data/A12/internal.log
/mnt/user/system/output/results.dt
```

Select answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. If the exclusion contains only words and de selected_files only phrases, i would work. but here, my files contains paths. I guess the / makes the thing not working...

Comment: Hello,  first cat did nothing, the second almost worked, it only deleted the last line with the .tmp, and if I add the .sh in exclusion, it will also delete it. I doesn't search for a word inside the line.

Comment: what do you mean?? check and try again  corrected your command

Comment: it doesn't work as expected. after searching a bit, som of my export files are in CR/LP and others just in LP. I'm going to search this way

Comment: got it to work, it was the return carrier. but I still have an issue with spaces in the path :-/

Comment: give some example why spaces not working. if you provise regex /usr/mnt/input and you want to remove both /usr/mnt/input and /usr/mn t/input. ??

Comment: I added it to the original post but here /mnt/user/system/output/test space/test.tmp and I want to remove .tmp. the output x shows /mnt/user/system/output/test and space/test.tmp on seperate lines.

Comment: add constraint on regex sed "/^"$(echo "${x//\//\\\/}")"$/d" so that it will match entire line as regex